# Get rid of meta characters in vim's perldoc viewer

Tags: vimscript

If I do `:Perldoc version` for documents longer than one page, I see output like this:

```
ESC[1mNAMEESC[0m
version - Perl extension for Version Objects

ESC[1mSYNOPSISESC[0m
  # Parsing version strings (decimal or dotted-decimal)
```

Note the distracting "ESC" and other weird characters in there that make it difficult to read the headings. For shorter documents that fit in one page, everything looks fine.

Any good way of fixing this?

**EDIT**

The following is used in my .vimrc to look up the perldoc:

```
set keywordprg=pd

function! CallPerldoc ()
    " When editing Vim files, revert to :help...
    if &filetype == 'vim' || &buftype == 'help'
        return ":help "

    " Otherwise use Perldoc...
    else 
        let target = matchstr(expand('<cfile>'), '\w\+\(::\w\+\)*')
        set wildmode=list:full
        return ":Perldoc "
    endif
endfunction

"Complete perldoc requests with names of installed Perl modules
command! -nargs=? -complete=customlist,CompletePerlModuleNames Perldoc  call Perldoc_impl(<q-args>)
"    
"Undo the special wildmoding and then execute the requested perdoc lookup...
function! Perldoc_impl (args)
    set wildmode=list:longest,full
    if empty(a:args)
        exec '!pd %'
    else
        exec '!pd ' . a:args
    endif
endfunction

" Compile the list of installed Perl modules (and include the name under the cursor)...
let s:module_files = readfile($HOME.'/.vim/perlmodules')
function! CompletePerlModuleNames(prefix, cmdline, curpos)
    let cfile = expand('<cfile>')
    let prefix = a:prefix
    if prefix == cfile
        let prefix = ""
    endif
    if empty(prefix) && cfile =~ '^\w\+\(::\w\+\)*$'
        return [cfile] + filter(copy(s:module_files), 'v:val =~ ''\c\_^' . prefix. "'")
    else
        return filter(copy(s:module_files), 'v:val =~ ''\c\_^' . prefix. "'")
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Are you using this plugin? https://github.com/hotchpotch/perldoc-vim

Comment: No, I'll check it out, though.

Comment: Then I'm curious where your command comes from. I don't have a `:Perldoc`. What does `:verbose command Perldoc` report?

Comment: `Name        Args       Address   Complete  Definition
    Perldoc     ?                    customlist    call Perldoc_impl(<q-args>)`

Comment: I just added the code that is used to generate the prompt and pull up the perldocs.

Comment: check how you call perldoc. you might want to use the switch `-otext`